# Make last cell in row active

Tags: excel, vba

How can I, using the code below, replace "B5" by the "LastCol" so that I can activate the last non-blank cell in a row?

```
Sub LastColumnInOneRow()
'Find the last used column in a Row: row 1 in this example
    Dim LastCol As Integer
    With ActiveSheet
        LastCol = .Cells(6, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With

    Worksheets("WARNINGS").Range("B5").Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Activate
End Sub
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do like this:

```
Sub LastColumnInOneRow()
'Find the last used column in a Row: row 1 in this example
    Dim LastCol As Integer
    With ActiveSheet
        LastCol = .Cells(6, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With
    With Worksheets("WARNINGS")
        .Activate
        .Cells(5,LastCol).Activate
    End With
    ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Activate
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The question took me a minute to figure out but try this

```
Worksheets("WARNINGS").Cells(6, LastCol + 1).Activate
```

at the end.

```
    Sub LastColumnInOneRow()
    'Find the last used column in a Row: row 1 in this example

    Dim LastCol As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        LastCol = .Cells(6, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With


    Worksheets("WARNINGS").Cells(6, LastCol + 1).Activate

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Excellent! Many thanks. Here is the one I used at the end.

This was a first step towards sorting a pivot table results. 
I saved a macro to sort the values but am now getting a "Subscript out of Range" warning when I try to run it. I guess the macro script is using a static range that I need to replace so that it can run to whatever Pivot Table results I may have.

But which line of the macro code do I need to replace?

```
Sub SortLargestWarningsCount()
```

'Find the last used column in a Row: row 1 in this example

```
Dim LastCol As Integer
    With ActiveSheet
        LastCol = .Cells(6, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With

Worksheets("WARNINGS").Cells(6, LastCol).Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
```

'Sort from Largest

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("WarningsPivotTable").PivotFields( _
    "[Warnings].[Column5].[Column5]").AutoSort xlDescending, _
    "[Measures].[Count of Column5]", ActiveSheet.PivotTables("WarningsPivotTable"). _
    PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines(12), 1
```

End Sub